# Attach command to execute when long-running thread returns

Tags: bash

Let's say I've just started a command that will take a long time to execute, like `hg clone` the entire Pypy development set. Halfway through, I decide I'd like to run another process, like `hg up`, once the first one returns. Is there a way to attach a command to execute when the process returns, without stopping the command/process and then restarting it as a chained command? command/process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `bash`, and assuming you placed the long-running task into the background of the current shell, either by running `longtask &` or by starting the task then hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, then you can add an extra command to run, eg:

```
$ sleep 45 &
[1] 27722
$ wait 27722 && echo "Done"
[1]+  Done   sleep 45
Done
$
```

In the example above, the `echo "Done"` is only executed after completion of the `wait` on PID 27722.

The thing I've not found is a way to put this additional command into the background to allow you to carry on working in the same shell.  There must be a way to do it though - this should hopefully give you a start.